# Problems with file share permission on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows

I am using Windows Server 2012 and want to create a share drive (`S:`). Inside the drive I want to create folders with specific permissions to the users.

- I tried to create a Read access only to the drive (`S:`). Inside the drive I created a folder (`Hello\`) and provided Read&Write access to the same user. An error appears: `You need permission to perform this action`.
- If I change the `S:` drive permission to Read & Write, the user can create folders in the `Hello\` folder, but also to the the `S:` drive. I want to provide access only to the specific sub-folders.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as "shared drive `S:` permissions". There's exactly two kind of permissions:

- Share permissions affects how an user can use share `\\SERVER\share$`, connected as `S:`. Before NTFS there was only this kind of permissions, so folder needed to be shared separately to achieve this. In your scenario with NTFS the user should have *Read & Write* permissions.
- NTFS permission affects on how an user can use files and folders. Let's assume the `\\SERVER\share$` corresponds to the folder `D:\share\`. Here, you can set the `D:\share\` folder permissions as *Read only* for the user, and `D:\share\subfolder` as *Read & Write*.

In order to do something a user needs to have both share and NTFS permissions for that.

Comment: the issue is that the users can create folders in the S drive and I want them only to have the access to specific folders .. Moreover i cannot provide only the folder map as the users are using different PC's on daily base.

Comment: ...and this answers to this problem. Users must have write permission on the share, but only read NTFS permission to its root folder.